# Clear functool's lru_cache once datastructure is written

Tags: python, functools

I have a problem understanding how to apply the `@lru_cache` decorator properly. I have a dictionary `attribute` that computes values by calling another function on a list of values. I want to cache any access to `attribute`. Is there any way to declare the lru_cache invalid whenever there is a write to `some_list`? So far, the code is as follows:

```py
@property
@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def attribute(self):
    attribute = {}
    for k in self.some_dict:
        attribute[k] = self.complex_computation(self.some_list)

    return attribute
```

Comment: ``lru_cache`` has a ``clear`` method. What problem do you have calling it?

Comment: Note that there is also ``functools.cached_property``. This might be more appropriate for caching a single attribute.

Answer (score -1):

It would be better to use `@lru_cache` for your `self.complex_computation` method.

`@lru_cache` saves **function_calls**, which is, basically function + args + return_value. So there must be a dependency between `return` value and args, but `property` doesn't have this dependency - you just always pass the same `self` here.

But `self.complex_computation` has such a parameter and it's really more suitable for the `@lru_cache` decorator. But rememeber - @lru_cache does not work for **List** arguments.

Comment: ``@lru_cache`` does *not* work for list arguments! It is not suitable to apply to ``self.complex_computation``.

Comment: fixed it just now